# How to access Func/Action delegate parameter values?

Tags: c#, delegates, action, func

I'm writing a method to make some measurements of other methods

Something like this, and this example runs as expected:

```
public void RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn(Action actionToMeasure)
{
    //some stuff here

    actionToMeasure(); //call method execution

    //some stuff here
}

//method call would be:
RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn(new Action(actionToMeasure));
```

But I also need to make this work for methods/procedures with parameters

For example

```
public void RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn(Action<int> actionToMeasure)
{
//stuff...

**how can I call actionToMeasure with it's parameters here?**

//stuff...
}
```

I guess I could make this measurement method like this:

```
public void RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn(Action<int> actionToMeasure, int parameter)
{
//do stuff

actionToMeasure(parameter);

//do stuff
}
```

but that would mean, that my function call would be like this
`RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn(new Action<int>(actionToMeasure), parameterValue);`

but I would prefer to call it something like this
`RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn(new Action<int>(actionToMeasure(parameterValue));`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn(MethodWithNoParams);
RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn(() => { MethodWithOneParam(5); });

public void MethodWithNoParams()
{
    Console.WriteLine("MethodWithNoParams");
}

public void MethodWithOneParam(int a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MethodWithOneParam: " + a);
}
```

And keep this how you had it:

```
public void RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn(Action actionToMeasure)
{
    //some stuff here

    actionToMeasure(); //call method execution

    //some stuff here
}
```

The trick is: You pass it an anonymous function, with no parameters, which itself calls the parameterised method.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working! :) I guess for Func's I would need to have `public void RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn(Func<TResult> function)` and otherwise it should be the same as with Action's, right?

Comment: Ok, this is a really nice trick - thanks again for the fast and quality answer!

Comment: @Prokurors Yep, you're correct about the `Func`s - just be aware that you're essentially throwing away the return value. Might be better to write: `public T RunMethodWithMeasurementsOn<T>(Func<T> function)` and have the method return the result after the second `//some stuff here`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it like this:

```
public void Foo(Action<int> action, int parameter)
{
    action(parameter);
}
```

First parameter doesn't hold action's parameter. Its only code that will be executed. So you have to provide this parameter some other way.